# how to git pull automatically when working on same branch

Tags: git

in git flow, you have `master`, `dev`, `feature/*` branches.

developers should checkout from `dev` to `feature/*` branch when they start working on something.

But I've found that when someone else pushes to `dev` branch first, another person should pull `dev` first in order to push properly.

So, it goes like this.

1. work on feature and commit.
2. checkout to `dev` branch and merge `feature/*`.
3. git push, and gets rejected because someone else pushed first.

To prevent this, one should `git pull origin dev` before merging. Is there any way to automate this step?

Comment: A `git pull` may cause conflicts that need a human brain to resolve. Trying to automate this step will eventually end in tears and frustration.

Comment: You can run `git pull origin --rebase=merges dev` after merging, so that you won't get another merge commit. It's not a good idea to automate `git pull` before merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to *rebase* first your feature branch on top of the target branch (here dev)

```bash
# update dev with the latest
git switch dev
git pull

# rebase myFeature on top of dev
git switch myFeature
git rebase dev

# then the merge is trivial
git switch dev
git merge myFeature
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but here's my take:

On teams that I work with, we never push to the dev branch. Instead we create
a Pull Request from the feature branch to the dev branch. We also have a requirement that the feature branch must have the most up-to-date version of the dev branch merged into it before a Pull Request is accepted.

In some projects, we take this a step further and eliminate the dev branch. We just have `main`. Feature branches are created from `main` and Pull Requests are made back to `main`.